# javax.mail not sends emails and not showing any error

Tags: java, linux, email, centos, jakarta-mail

I have some Java function that should send emails to users.

In the past this function works as well, but i dont understand why it is not working anymore.

When i try to use this function, it is not send email and it is not show any error.

Can you explain me what could be the problem?

[The tool that contains this function, run on a Linux server (CentOS)]

---

This is the function:

```
public static void sendEmail(String to) throws JSONException, IOException {
        String from = "test@test.com";                  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String host = "localhost";                                  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();             // Get system properties
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);             // Setup mail server
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);   // Get the default Session object.

        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));             // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));    // Set To: header field of the header.

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("Some test subjet");

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("test message");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
        }
        catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does it **not send** the email or perhaps the recipients **do not receive** it? How do you know which one is the case?

Comment: Have you debugged it? Have you monitored the mail server logs, if the message is being transferred?

Comment: "It used to work but it doesn't work anymore."  Ok, so what changed?  If you don't know what changed, you're going to have to debug the program.  See the [debugging tips in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and this list of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).